# How to choose best Block size when uploading to an Azure Block Blob

Tags: c#, windows, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I have created a C# DotNet utility that uploads a large file to an Azure Block Blob. I am trying to determine the best block size for uploading.  I have tried all different values from small to very large and they seem to have little or no impact on performance. Is there any reason not to just go to the maximum block size (100MB I believe)?  What are some of the things to consider when choosing the block size?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to choose blob block size in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44775415/how-to-choose-blob-block-size-in-azure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the link [How to choose blob block size in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44775415/how-to-choose-blob-block-size-in-azure) provided by Alexander, here is a suggestion:

You don't need to create your own .net utility and consider how to set the best block size. There is already a .net library provided by azure storage team: [Microsoft Azure Storage Data Movement Library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement#microsoft-azure-storage-data-movement-library-110).

The `Microsoft Azure Storage Data Movement Library` designed for high-performance uploading, downloading and copying Azure Storage Blob and File.

And for larger files, this library has good performance, we have used it many times. You should consider directly using it for your purpose.